# Post Processing Algorithm

Tags: gps, post-processing

I am working on project In which I am supposed to make a web app which will be asking users to upload their inputs as "Rinex file" of Rover and Base Station and It will give more precise data after differential correction.

So I just want to know the algorithm of post processing kinematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for source code, I will suggest you go through http://www.rtklib.com/.

There you can find library for post processing kinematics

Comment: I know it man but I want its algorithm because its written in c and I am not good at c.
Once I will know its algorithm I will code it In Python.